# upload application which backend is django and frontend is Vue using Docker

Tags: django, docker, vue.js, traefik

I'm working on an application which uses these technologies:

- Django Backend
- Vue JS front end
- PostgreSQL database
- Docker as a container
- Traefik as a reverse proxy version 1.7
- redis.
- awscli

Here is my **production.yml** file which i use to the docker-compose to run all applications:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  production_postgres_data: {}
  production_postgres_data_backups: {}
  production_traefik: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: goplus_backend_production_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - ./static:/static # adding static & media file for django
      - ./media:/media
  
  vue:
    build:
      context: /root/goplus_front/new_dashboard_v2
    container_name: new_dashboard_v2
    environment:
      - HOST=localhost
      - PORT=8080 
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - django

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: goplus_backend_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - production_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - production_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  
  traefik:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/traefik/Dockerfile
    image: goplus_backend_production_traefik
    depends_on:
      - django
#    volumes:
     # - production_traefik:/etc/traefik/acme
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0
  awscli:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/aws/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
    volumes:
      - production_postgres_data_backups:/backups
```

Till now everything is fine and if I use **IP:80** I got redirected to Django app (admin panel), and if I use **IP:8080** I got redirection to Vue app.
The problem is now I want to use **Domain Name** not IP address, I bought a domain name and add SSL to it and it is working fine if I try to access Django app but not working if I try to access Vue app.
Here is the configuration file for **traefik.toml** which responsible of redirect requests to Django or Vue:

```
logLevel = "INFO"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

# Entrypoints, http and https
[entryPoints]
  # http should be redirected to https
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  # https is the default
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "/etc/certs/<crt_file_name>.crt"
      keyFile  = "/etc/certs/<crt_key_file_name>.key"

[file]
[backends]
  [backends.django]
    [backends.django.servers.server1]
      url = "http://django:5000"

  [backends.vue]
    [backends.vue.servers.server1]
      url = "http://vue:8080"

[frontends]
  [frontends.django]
    backend = "django"
    passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.django.headers]
      HostsProxyHeaders = ['X-CSRFToken']
    [frontends.django.routes.dr1]
      rule = "Host:<domain name>, <IP name>"

  [frontends.vue]
    backend = "vue"
    [frontends.vue.routes.dr1]
       rule = "Host:<domain name>;PathPrefixStrip:/dashboard"
```

So from that configuration i want if someone tries to access Django app he must just use **the Full domain name**, and if he wants to use Vue app he must use **DomainName/dashboard**, it is working fine with Django app but with Vue app i got these Errors.
[image]
so any help or recommendation to solve this problem?